# Full Calendar - not implementing time dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am dynamically implementing the events in calendar using javascript.

Let me tell you how it actually build

1. Clicking a button opens a  BS 4 modal.
2. Modal container [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) ( I am using it just for date not for time )
3. For selection of time I have added custom select options.
4. add event fields name, description etc.
5. after clicking the add button modal disapper and the event is successfully add.

***So what's the problem.***

The problem is when I statically add the event it gets me this ( The expected result );

[image]

But,,

When I try to do it dynamically it gets me this ( Non Expected result );

[image]

So to know that my time is implementing I have used `eventClick();` which is in-built in fullcalendar

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    console.log(info);
    console.log(info.start._i);
    console.log(info.end._i);
}
```

`info.start._i` get the date with time as expected and `info.end._i` get the date with time as expected. So why I am getting non expected result.

Comment: This is all very interesting, but we can't magically guess what you did wrong in your invisible code. We'd like to help you, but without seeing some relevant code and sample data, it's not really possible. I'm sure you would agree you would have the same difficulty if someone else gave you this description and you had never seen their application before. Please can you update your question to contain enough useful detail? Thanks.

Comment: P.S. please also tell us your version of fullCalendar, since the way of writing the calendar code is very different in the newly released v4 than it was in v3 and earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar end date wrong by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407052/fullcalendar-end-date-wrong-by-one-day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured it out the issue is `allDay` is `true` is should be set to `false`