# Full calendar display start date and end date but end date wrong display

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have to use fullCalendar.

The problem is my event's end date is `28-11-2019` but in the calendar it displays as `27-11-2019`.

What is the solution?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    events: "php/fetch-event.php",
    eventOrder:('-batch'),
    displayEventTime: false,
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
      if (event.batch  === 'morning') {
        element.css('background-color', '#7cbfe5');
      } 
      else  {
        element.css('background-color', '#9fe78d');
      }
    },
  });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar end date wrong by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407052/fullcalendar-end-date-wrong-by-one-day)

Comment: There is already a long discussion on this topic : https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3679

Comment: In addition to the above, did you read the part of the documentation where it explains that end dates are **exclusive**? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object