# Full Calendar All Day event showing on wrong day

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Can anyone tell me why my event that is marked as an All Day Event would show up on the calendar on November 24th instead of the 25th? The start and end dates appear correct but it is adding it to the wrong day. I would like to figure out why instead of writing code to fix this for all day events.

json related output:

```
"allDay": true,
"end":"2021-11-25T23:59:00Z",
"start":"2021-11-25T00:00:00Z",
"title":"HOLIDAY -  Thanksgiving Day (All U.S. Offices)"
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your timezone, but maybe you should addapt your timezone as explained [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing):

> 2018-06-01T12:30:00Z — **Z signifies 00:00 UTC offset**

Check your UTC timezone based in this [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#/media/File:World_Time_Zones_Map.png).

If you are using the correct UTC for your location or after fixing your UTC zone do not fix your problem, then you should check this other post related a problems with `end:` dates:

[Fullcalendar end date wrong by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407052/fullcalendar-end-date-wrong-by-one-day)

In my case, when I set `allDay: true` for a record in my fullcalendar (my own agenda), I am adding always a day more in the fullcalendar json string like this:

```
"allDay": true,
"end":"2021-12-19T09:00:00",
"start":"2021-12-18T08:00:00"
```

despite the correct data stored in database is `2021-12-18T09:00:00`.